# Issue with requiring a package from node modules in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, jquery-plugins

I have a javascript file as follows

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.jqueryvalidation = require('jquery-validation');

Vue.component('error-message', require('./components/Flash_Error_Message.vue'));
Vue.component('like', require('./components/Like.vue'));


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});

$(function(){
    $('#postForm').validate({
        rules:{
            body:{
                required:true,
            },
            study:{
                required:true,
                digits:true,
            },

        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            $(element).closest('.form-control').css("border-color","#a94442");
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            $(element).closest('.form-control').css("border-color","#00b8e6");
        },
        messages:{
            study:{
                required:"Please provide a channel of study for your post"
            },
        }
    });
})
```

As you can see i am requiring the jquery-validation package from node modules correctly and i have installed it properly however when i open my browser google chrome i get this console error validate is not a function this only occurs when you haven't included the jquery-validation but from the code you can see it there so why do i get this error ? It should be noted that when i include jquery validation through a cdn the error is gone but i would like to understand why this code isn't working as intended. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use your browser's DOM inspection tools to see if the script is there, and if so, see if the URL is broken?  At least you'd know where to start.

Comment: You said it works when you use a CDN.  Based on what you've shown us, how are we supposed to know where you've placed the plugin in your directory structure?

Comment: The jquery-validation was installed using npm  so its placed in my node_modules folder eg. Project/node_modules/jquery-validation as for DOM when i check the page source its there all the jquery-validation functions including validate.